# Save Image in Qt

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator, qt-designer

Im new using Qt designer and I need to create an Image Processor Software for a final exam, and im trying to use Qt Designer. I need to open an image, apply different modifications, go to the next or previous image in the folder, and save the image.
To open the images I use the next code:

```
image = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"), QDir::homePath(), tr("PNM (*.pnm *.pbm *.pgm *.ppm);; AIC(*.aic)")); 

if (!image.isEmpty()){
    QImage img(image);
    QPixmap pix = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
    int w = ui->foto->width();
    int h = ui->foto->height();
    ui->photo->setPixmap(pix.scaled(w,h,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
}else{
    QMessageBox::critical(this,"Error","Can't open image");
}
```

Image is a private QString in the headers file. I used a label in the ui to open images from the computer's folders, since one of the things that the proggrame has to do is open files from a directory chosen by the user.

It opens the images without problem, but when I try to save them, it doesn't create the new image. Im using the next code to try save it:

```
if(!image.isEmpty()){
    image = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,tr("Save Image"), "ImgEdited", tr("PNM (*.pnm *.pbm *.pgm *.ppm);; AIC (*.aic)"));
    ui->photo->pixmap()->save(image);

    if(!ui->photo->pixmap()->save(image)){
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "Image couldn't be saved");
    }

}else{
        QMessageBox::warning(this, " ", "There's no open image");
}
```

I want to know which is the problem, if i'm doing it correctly or if there is another way to do it. Also I want to know how to change to the previous or next image in the folder.
All help is welcome!!

Comment: In which format do you try to save your images?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all images in some forder use these function:

```
 const QString pathToFolder = "/home/user/images";
 const QDir foldersDir(pathToFolder);
        const QStringList allImages= foldersDir.entryList(QStringList() << "*.jpg", QDir::Files);
        for (const QString &fileName : allImages)
        {
            const QString fullPath = pathToFolder + QDir::separator() + fileName;
            QImage image(fullPath );
            
        }
```

File saving method has signature:

```
static QString getSaveFileName(QWidget *parent = nullptr,
                               const QString &caption = QString(),
                               const QString &dir = QString(),
                               const QString &filter = QString(),
                               QString *selectedFilter = nullptr,
                               Options options = Options());
```

You have ImgEdited as dir or **part** of fullName of your saving fileName.Add format for example `png` to save.

`image +=".png";`

after `getSaveFileName`;